# Generating a full UTF-8 webpage out of a Markdown file

Tags: html, markdown

When I use the Markdown Perl script, I only get an HTML `<body>`, but nothing around that. Is there some way to wrap it in a whole HTML file which specifies UTF-8 encoding in the header?

Comment: [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used it, but it looks like [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) has this feature. See `4.2 Complete documents vs “snippets”` in [MultiMarkdown Manual](http://fletcher.github.com/peg-multimarkdown/mmd-manual.pdf).

Comment: This looks promising, since it is completely compatable with the main Markdown Syntax. Thanks!